# WASM+UDF performance comparison in Scylladb, why there is no obvious differance?

Tags: performance, lua, user-defined-functions, webassembly, scylla

I write an add function in wasm to test the performance of WASM in Scylladb, at the same time, I write the add function with lua to compare the performance. However, there is no obvious difference   between the two languages compiled into UDF, this is why?
when the amount of computation is 1000000:
the execution time of wasm is:15258844ms
the execution time of lua is: 17901003ms

I expect this comparison can demonstrate the performance advantage of WASM in UDF

Comment: What does "the amount of computation is 1000000" mean? Do you have you have 1000000 items and want to add them all up using a user-defined **aggregation** (like a home-made version of the "sum" aggregation)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have 1000000 items, and add them alone.For example, 1+2=3,  two parameters for one result. Execute add for 1000000 times!

Answer (score 0):

According to your clarification in the comment, you have 1000000 separate items, and invoke a trivial addition operation on each one. Clearly in this case, the overhead of reading and parsing each item can outweight the trivial computation of the addition, so whether the function is interpreted in Lua or WASM makes little difference.

Also, looking at the actual numbers you reported, dividing the total time by number of items we get 15ms per item. That's a **huge** amount of time that is orders of magnitude slower than addition in WASM or Lua. Even a small cluster should be able to read much more than 65 items per second in a scan. This suggests to me you did something wrong... Did you actually read the items in a scan, or one by one in individual requests? If you used individual requests, did you parallelize them, or just sent them one by one? Sending individual requests one by one just means that 15ms is your request latency - which has nothing to do with the throughput that your cluster is capable of. Please look at Scylla's monitoring to verify that your cluster is 100% utilized, or at least significantly utilized - if you see it's 5% utilized, your numbers are fairly meaningless.

In any case, the performance difference between Lua and WASM, if it's significant, will only be visible in long and complex functions that need to run a lot of code. What you did (a single addition) is almost like writing an "hello world" program in Python and C++, and then being surprised both finish in 0.1 seconds - which is neither an indication of which language is more efficient, nor a good measurement of each language's performance (it doesn't take 0.1 seconds to print a single line to the output in either languague).